# Crash on presenting UIImageViewController at iPad in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iPad app that should works only at Landscape mode.
But I have to show `UIImagePickerController`.
According to documentation `UIImageController` works only with Portrait mode.

If I disabple Portrait orientation and present `UIImageViewController` I receive crash with

> "Supported orientations has no common orientation with the
>   application, and `[PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate]`”

How I can configure project to disable Portrait mode at iPad and allow to show `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: Do you show ImagePicker in Popover?

Comment: No. I made self.present(<Instance of UIImagePicker>)

Comment: If popover style doesn't conflict with your requirements, set modalPresentationStyle to .popover (it's property in UIImagePickerController)

Comment: UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7fa0024589b0>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.

Comment: RTFM. You should use Popover presentation for it on iPad

Answer (score 1):

My solution without setting Portrait mode

```
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    imagePicker.sourceType = (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) ? .camera : .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice. As you have already said, the solution is to enable portrait orientation in your app.

If the intersection between what the view controller requires and what the app permits is null, the app will crash (as you have seen).

Comment: And how I can resolve it? App should works only at Landscape without rotation to portrait